# It is EXISTS function somehow confusing?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

- t1 (col) with values (1), (2)
- t2 (col) with values (1)

This query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE t1.col >= 2)
```

returns both rows from `t1`, and this is ok, because `EXISTS` returns at least one row, so where clause becomes TRUE.

Now the second query

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t1.col = t2.col)
```

This returns only 1 row. Why? in this case `EXISTS` also returns at least one row, so why not all rows returned from "t1" table?

How does the `EXISTS()` function really work ?

Comment: `EXISTS` is evaluating the condition for each row in `t1`.  There is no match in `t2` where `t1.col = 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first query, there is no reference to the outer table inside your `exists()`, and since that query evaluates to true your query becomes

```
select * from t1 where 1 = 1 ;
```

Your second query does have a reference to the outer table inside your `exists()` and is evaluated for each values of `t1.col`. So for the row where `t1.col = 1` your `exists()` returns `true`, when `t1.col = 2` then your `exists()` returns false. So your result set only includes the row where `t1.col = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS returns true if it finds one or more records.
Since you have column t1 with values 1 and 2 and t2 with value 1.

This

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t1.col = t2.col)
```

now means

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE 1 = 1)
```

So you get only 1 row and not 2.